# python/numpy array: replace item by item N rows before

Tags: arrays, numpy, replace, python-3.6

In python 3 (3.6.5), I have data in a (much longer) numpy array looking like this:

```
data = np.array([[16347,     0,    60],[16353,     0,    92],[16382,     0,     1],[17867,     0,     2],[20188,     0,     3],[21459,     0,   512],[21873,     0,    71],[22031,     0,     4],[23072,     0,    61],[25378,     0,    60],[25385,     0,    82],[25410,     0,     1],[26895,     0,     2],[29233,     0,     3],[31695,     0,    71],[31845,     0,     4],[32886,     0,    61],[35069,     0,    60],[35075,     0,    90],[35104,     0,     1]])
```

The first two columns can be ignored for the point of this question. In the third, I would like to replace all `2` entries with a value in the same column, 2 rows before. For instance, in the example data there is a `2` on the 4th row, and it should be replaced by the number `92`in row 2. Similarly, the `2` on row 13 needs to be replaced by `82` on line 11, and so on.

In short, I need to search for all `2` entries in a column within a numpy array, and replace them for whatever value was on the same column 2 rows before.

I'd appreciate any tips or ideas. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the np.where() and np.roll() to do this:

```
data[:,-1]=where(data[:,-1]==2,np.roll(data[:,-1],2),data[:,-1])
```

Here

```
data[:,-1]
```

Isolates the 3rd column you are interested in, and where() returns an array filled with values that depend on the condition. If the condition that the value is equal to 2 is True, it returns the corresponding value from

```
np.roll(data[:,-1],2)
```

which is the original column shifted forward by 2, with the last two values no becoming the first two values.

There result for the input array:

```
[[16347     0    60]
 [16353     0    92]
 [16382     0     1]
 [17867     0     2]
 [20188     0     3]
 [21459     0   512]
 [21873     0    71]
 [22031     0     4]
 [23072     0    61]
 [25378     0    60]
 [25385     0    82]
 [25410     0     1]
 [26895     0     2]
 [29233     0     3]
 [31695     0    71]
 [31845     0     4]
 [32886     0    61]
 [35069     0    60]
 [35075     0    90]
 [35104     0     1]]
```

is the desired:

```
[[16347     0    60]
 [16353     0    92]
 [16382     0     1]
 [17867     0    92]
 [20188     0     3]
 [21459     0   512]
 [21873     0    71]
 [22031     0     4]
 [23072     0    61]
 [25378     0    60]
 [25385     0    82]
 [25410     0     1]
 [26895     0    82]
 [29233     0     3]
 [31695     0    71]
 [31845     0     4]
 [32886     0    61]
 [35069     0    60]
 [35075     0    90]
 [35104     0     1]]
```

Comment: Fantastic! That is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!